# Testing cherrypy WSGI application using Webtest and or nose?

Tags: python, testing, cherrypy, nose, webtest

How to test a cherrypy application with json or html result widely with [nose](http://code.google.com/p/python-nose) and [webtest](https://webtest.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) using WSGI interface?

any example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this example may help:

```
from webtest import TestApp
from nose.tools import eq_

class TestAuthentication(object):
    """
    Tests for the default authentication setup.

    If your application changes how the authentication layer is configured
    those tests should be updated accordingly
    """

    application_under_test = 'main'

    def setUp(self):
        """Method called by nose before running each test"""
        # Loading the application:
        conf_dir = config.here
        wsgiapp = loadapp('config:test.ini#%s' % self.application_under_test,
                          relative_to=conf_dir)
        self.app = TestApp(wsgiapp)
        # Setting it up:
        test_file = path.join(conf_dir, 'test.ini')
        cmd = SetupCommand('setup-app')
        cmd.run([test_file])

    def tearDown(self):
        """Method called by nose after running each test"""
        # Cleaning up the database:
        model.DBSession.remove()
        teardown_db()

    def test_forced_login(self):
        """Anonymous users are forced to login

        Test that anonymous users are automatically redirected to the login
        form when authorization is denied. Next, upon successful login they
        should be redirected to the initially requested page.

        """
        # Requesting a protected area
        resp = self.app.get('/secc/', status=302)
        assert resp.location.startswith('http://localhost/login')
        # Getting the login form:
        resp = resp.follow(status=200)
        print resp.forms
        form = resp.forms
        # Submitting the login form:
        form['login'] = u'manager'
        form['password'] = 'managepass'
        post_login = form.submit(status=302)
        # Being redirected to the initially requested page:
        assert post_login.location.startswith('http://localhost/post_login')
        initial_page = post_login.follow(status=302)
        assert 'authtkt' in initial_page.request.cookies, \
               "Session cookie wasn't defined: %s" % initial_page.request.cookies
        assert initial_page.location.startswith('http://localhost/secc/'), \
               initial_page.location
```